# MS Word 2013 | IncludeText contains paragraph marks invisible to VBA

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, field-codes

In a Word 2013 document I have an `INCLUDETEXT` field followed by some text:

```
|--THE FIELD ↓------------| |---------SOME TEXT ↓---------------------|
{ INCLUDETEXT MyFile.docx } A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.¶
```

After I calculate the field, I get:

```
Hi!¶
Hello!¶
A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.¶
```

**PROBLEM:** 
Word does not recognize the paragraph marks in the field value and when instructed to select the last paragraph via VBA, it selects all three:

```
>Hi!¶
Hello!¶
A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.¶<
```

instead of

```
Hi!¶
Hello!¶
>A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.¶<
```

**WHY I NEED THIS TO WORK:** My macro runs a Find&Replace command whose scope is supposed to be limited to the last paragraph only — but in actuality, its scope extends to the contents of the first two

I'm looking for a workaround and at 4 AM my mind doesn't want to supply a good and simple idea… One possible solution is to just insert a paragraph mark right after the field but this gives me doubled paragraph marks, i.e. an empty paragraph.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: If you found the answer, could you post it please? Since you asked in April, I doubt you are still looking for an answer, but if you are, please respond.

Comment: Well, I use a workaround, whereby I manually insert something called a Style Separator after each field. You press Ctrl+Alt+Enter and you get a sort of a hidden paragraph mark. You can read more about it here: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Style_Separator

Comment: Thanks very much. If you can write it up as an Answer rather than a comment it would help “close” this question. You can mark your own answer as The Answer.